# React Native project stuck on loading screen

Tags: react-native, mobile-development

I'm trying to get data from an url with axios but my app is stuck on loading screen like this:

[Photo of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bowbp.png)

code of the fetch request:

```
import axios from 'axios'
import {useState,useEffect} from 'react'

function useFetch(url){

    const[loading,setLoading] = useState(true)
    const[data, setData] = useState([])
    const[error, setError] = useState(null)

    const fetchData = async () => {
        try{

            const {data: responseData} = await axios.get(url)
            setData(responseData)
            setLoading(false)

        }catch(err){    
            setError(err.message)
            setLoading(false)
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {fetchData()},[])
    return{loading,data,error}
}

export default useFetch
```

how I import fetch:

> ```
> const {loading,data,error} = useFetch("https://fakestoreapi.com/products")
> ```

The same code worked before but it's not working anymore. Any help is appreciated.

I tried reseting caches but it didn't help either.

Comment: I added the fetch code. Actually, I run the project in a different wifi then mine in the first place, is this the cause of the problem?

Comment: you need to provide code which describe how you handle the loading state

Comment: @baristp04 WIFI is only a problem if you are calling an API from your machine (for example: 192.166.x.xx), And if you change to another WIFI ,you need to change the IP address again. In your case, this is not the problem since you are calling from an existing server.   What do you get when you do console.log(loading, error, data) just below the useFetch(...)?

Answer (score 0):

```
import axios from 'axios'
import {useState,useEffect} from 'react'

function useFetch(url){

    const[loading,setLoading] = useState(false)
    const[data, setData] = useState([])
    const[error, setError] = useState(null)

    const fetchData = async () => {
        try{
            setLoading(true)
            const {data: responseData} = await axios.get(url)
            if(responseData){
              setData(responseData)
              setLoading(false)
            }

        }catch(err){    
            setError(err.message)
            setLoading(false)
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {fetchData()},[])
    return{loading,data,error}
}

export default useFetch
```

As this the function call while importing this will make the loading state by default true instead try this make the loading state true inside the fetch data and also make sure the url path is correct and connection.

https://axios-http.com/docs/res_schema axios documentation

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work for me too. Also, I'm sure that url path is correct provided that the same url worked before.

Comment: @baristp04 Confirm that the version of React and React Native you are using is compatible with axios and useEffect. Outdated versions might lead to unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Adding ".finally" could be a nice thing to not have to not have to set loading to false twice.

This is how I do mine:

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default useApi = (apiFunc) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const request = async (...args) => {
    setLoading(true);
    const response = await apiFunc(...args);
    setLoading(false);

    setError(!response.ok);
    setData(response.data);

    return response;
  };
  return { data, error, loading, request };
};
```